# how to skip a row when the calculation result is zero?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a question about excel...anyway here is my data :

[image]

i want to calculate the shortest distance for these 4 locations by comparing them against each other but i want to skip the calculation when it meets the same coordinates ...for example, i want to know the shortest distance between location A and location B, C, or D and so on but i don't want to compare location A with itself because that will give zero result....Do you know how to do that using excel formula? anyway the second column is latitude and the third column is longitude, and i want to put the result on the right of the longitude column..

here is the formula that i want to use to get the result :

```
=INDEX(6370.97327862*((2*ASIN(SQRT((SIN((RADIANS(C3)-RADIANS(C3:C6))/2)^2)+COS(RADIANS(C3))*COS(RADIANS(C3:C6))*(SIN((RADIANS(D3)-RADIANS(D3:D6))/2)^2))))),MATCH(MIN(SQRT((C3:C6)^2+(D3:D6)^2)),SQRT((C3:C6)^2+(D3:D6)^2),-1),1)
```

any help is very appreciated, thx

**EDIT :**

here is the input as text :

```
location A  15.20613944 120.5797483

Location B  15.21214563 121.777773

Location C  15.30023000 120.6565657

Location D  15.28993333 120.9067895
```

Comment: what formula would you use to get the distance between say location A and location b?

Comment: How were you planning on comparing A to B, A to C, A to D? What formula are you using that gives you a zero result?

Comment: i want to compare, for example, shortest distance between A and B, C, D and put the result on the right of the longitude column...the problem is when i want to do that it will give zero results because the formula will make location A compare with itself...i want to also compare the shortest distance between location B and A,C,D, and put the result on the right of longitude column

Comment: please show the formula you tried.

Comment: The reason I ask in my planer geometry was a LONG time ago, but could you not use Pythagorean's theorem: `SQRT((Bx-Ax)^2+(By-Ay)^2)`?

Comment: and do you want to return the distance or the location?

Comment: i want to return the shortest distance, for example, between A & B,C,or D, between B & A, C, or D and so on and put the result on the right on the longitude column

Comment: if you could give more accurate excel formula i will appreciate it

Comment: Any chance you can paste your inputs as text so they can be copied and tested? Also, would be helpful if you can also paste the expected answer along with the measured distance for each. This way we have some sample data we can paste into excel and test with. Curious to help with this one but I don't even know if my distance equation is working right since you didn't give us sample outputs

Comment: What is the calculated distance between just A & B and how did you calculate that distance? You are not giving anyone enough info to actually test. If you can tell me how to get the distance of just TWO points I am willing to take a shot at the problem but I can't confirm if I'm even calculating one right so not going to look until you can confirm the answer for one point

Answer (score 1):

If you want a strict formula:

```
=MIN(IFERROR(1/(1/(ROUND(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS($B$2:$B$5))*SIN(RADIANS(B2))+COS(RADIANS($B$2:$B$5))*COS(RADIANS(B2))*COS((RADIANS(C2))-(RADIANS($C$2:$C$5))))*3443.89849,3))),1E+99))
```

Depending on ones version this may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

If you want something slightly simpler use vba:

Building on the User Defined Function from [HERE](https://excel.tips.net/T003275_Calculating_the_Distance_between_Points.html), I added the ability to reference more than one:

```
Function CrowFlies(dlat1 As Range, dlon1 As Range, dlat2 As Double, dlon2 As Double) As Double()
    Pi = Application.Pi()
    
    
    earthradius = 3443.89849  'nautical miles
    
    Dim dlatArr() As Variant
    dlatArr = dlat1.Value
    
    Dim dlonarr() As Variant
    dlonarr = dlon1.Value
    
    Dim out() As Double
    ReDim out(1 To UBound(dlonarr, 1))
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(dlonarr, 1)
        
        lat1 = dlatArr(i, 1) * Pi / 180
        lat2 = dlat2 * Pi / 180
        lon1 = dlonarr(i, 1) * Pi / 180
        lon2 = dlon2 * Pi / 180
    
        cosX = Sin(lat1) * Sin(lat2) + Cos(lat1) _
          * Cos(lat2) * Cos(lon1 - lon2)
        out(i) = earthradius * Application.Acos(cosX)
    Next i
    
    CrowFlies = out
End Function
```

Then it is a simple call:

```
=MIN(IFERROR(1/(1/ROUND(CrowFlies($B$2:$B$5,$C$2:$C$5,B2,C2),3)),1E+99))
```

Depending on ones version this may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Usually I don't mind being outdone, but this was a tough one and I did not notice at all that you already posted a solution haha. Well done on formula solution as well. This one took me a lot of researching. I just bootstrapped the equation to a loop. Guessing your solution would destroy mine (time wise) on a larger data set. Curious to know the source of minor differences in solution output tho

Comment: Prob in difference in earth radius (3443.89849 compared to 3443.8985 from source I found online)

Comment: hello, i got 1E+99 when i tried to follow your first example using this excel formula :


=MIN(IFERROR(1/(1/(ROUND(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS($B$2:$B$5))*SIN(RADIANS(B2))+COS(RADIANS($B$2:$B$5))*COS(RADIANS(B2))*COS((RADIANS(C2))-(RADIANS($C$2:$C$5))))*3443.89849,3))),1E+99))

Comment: @DeadlyKitten999 his equation worked for me. Did you confirm formula with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

Answer (score 0):

This function takes in 2 location inputs *(The `Lat` and `Lon` for a target row)* and then compares these values to all other coordinates that exist in your table. The output will display the location that is closest along with the distance (n mi) seperated by column.

Note this assumes your full list of Latitudes exists in `Column C` and Longitudes in `Column D`

---

[image]

```
Public Function Shortest_Distance_Location(Lat As Range, Lon As Range) As String

Dim lr As Long
Dim xLat As Range, xLon As Range
lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim Pi As Double
Dim Convert As Double
Dim Temp1 As Double, Temp2 As Double, Temp3 As Double
Dim Temp4 As Double, Temp5 As Double, Temp6 As Double
Dim Temp_Answer As Double
Dim Shortest_Distance As Double
Dim Location As String

Pi = WorksheetFunction.Pi
Convert = 3443.8985
Shortest_Distance = 4000

For i = 2 To lr
    If i <> Lat.Row Then
        
        Set xLat = Range("B" & i)
        Set xLon = Range("C" & i)
        
        Temp1 = Sin(Lat * Pi / 180)
        Temp2 = Sin(xLat * Pi / 180)
        Temp3 = Cos(Lat * Pi / 180)
        Temp4 = Cos(xLat * Pi / 180)
        Temp5 = Cos(xLon * Pi / 180 - Lon * Pi / 180)
        Temp6 = WorksheetFunction.Acos(Temp1 * Temp2 + Temp3 * Temp4 * Temp5)
        Temp_Answer = Convert * Temp6
        
        If Temp_Answer < Shortest_Distance Then
            Shortest_Distance = Temp_Answer
            Location = Range("A" & i)
        End If
        
    End If
Next i

Shortest_Distance_Location = Location & ", " & Shortest_Distance
        
End Function
```

---

You can modify the last line if you only want the distance. I was just showing that you can get the min distance and the location (seems like you would want both).

Comment: If you understand the formula you can assign more meaningful names to the temp variables. I built this with no understanding of how the equation works. Instead, I just implemented a loop over a existing equation to find the distance between 2 points.